# Static (and nested!) class

Tags: c#, class, static, nested

I have a class which represents a game session, and I would like to have some sort of order, so that I could do something like this:

```
public class Session
{
    public static class Rooms
    {
        // All the things about session's rooms etc

        public static void Load()
        {
            // Load stuff...
        }
    }

    public static class Details
    {
        // All the session details (username, age...)
    }

    // etc
}
```

In this way, everything is more organized, and every nested class could work on specific stuff...

But, of course, there is a problem...

When I have an instance of the Session class, and I try to do something like the following:

```
Session x = new Session();

x.Rooms.Load();
```

I receive an error like this:

> Cannot reference a type through an expression. Try 'Program.Session.Rooms' instead.

Some hints, please?

Comment: What exactly were you thinking??!!!?? Why do `Rooms` and `Details` have to be static? Why not just make `Session` static? Why not just expose those two properties as...properties?

Comment: Session can't be static because every instance represents a different game session...

Comment: You realise the same goes for `Rooms` and `Details` right? There can only be one instance of them hanging around.

Comment: so why does anything at all have to be static?

Comment: @slugster I thought it could have been possible to have a non-static class to have its own static nested classes...

Answer (score 0):

The hint would be simply using what the error suggests:

```
Session.Rooms.Load();
```

To explain: Since `Session` is a *type*, i.e. not an *object* (instance of a type), and contains a nested static type. Therefore you still have to access the nested static type through the type `Session` and not through an instance of `Session`.

Comment: That's not a hint. That's the answer :P

Comment: Session is not static: every "Session" class represents a different game session, but every of them should have access to thoso other classes, "Rooms", "Details" etc...

Comment: @user1264377 I've added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a static class, you can access it like this

```
Session.Rooms.Load();
```

**EDIT :** As per your comment, You should probably change your class structure like this

> *every "Session" class represents a different game session, but every
>   of them should have access to thoso other classes, "Rooms", "Details*

```
public class Session
{
  public Rooms SessionRooms { set;get;}
  public Details SessionDetails { set;get;}
}

public class Rooms
{
  public void Load() {}
}

public class Details()
{
}
```

Here each Session object has it's own Rooms and Details. Those are specific to those Session objects.

Now you can do like this

```
Session objSes=new Session();
objSes.Rooms.Load();
```

Make sure you initialize your child properties (the other classes) before accessing them. Otherwise, you will get null reference exception.

**EDIT :** As per your comment, you want to to access the Details class inside Rooms class.In this case, I will add a ParentSession property to my Rooms class like this

```
public class Rooms
{
  public Session ParentSession { set;get;}

  public Rooms(Session parent)
  {
    this.ParentSession=parent;
  }

  public void Load() {}
}
```

And in your SessionClass, you pass the parent class object to the constructor of Rooms class

```
public class Session
{
  public Rooms SessionRooms { set;get;}
  public Details SessionDetails { set;get;}

  public Session()
  {
    if(this.SessionRooms==null)
    {
      this.SessionRooms=new Room(this);
    }
    if(this.SessionDetails ==null)
    {
      this.SessionDetails =new Details(this);
    }
  }
}
```

and you can access Details from Room like this

```
Session objSes=new Session();
//do something...

Room theRool=objSes.Room;
//now to access the details like    
theRoom.ParentSession.SessionDetails
```

Comment: Session is not static: every "Session" class represents a different game session, but every of them should have access to thoso other classes, "Rooms", "Details" etc...

Comment: Ok, I've got the point.... But in this case, it wouldn't be possible, for example, for the "Rooms" class to access any information in the "Details" class, isn't it?

Comment: @user1264377 Rooms class can only access the public properties exposed by Details class.

Comment: @user1264377 :Ok. Now i got your point. If you want The Rooms class to access Details class, i would add a PRoperty called "ParentSession" to Rooms class of type Session when creating the child instance and access the Details class like objRooms.ParentSession.SessionDetails.YourMethod..

Comment: It's what I'm trying to do now, but I have a question: when the value of my "Session" object changes, does the value of the property in the "Rooms", or "Details" (or whatever) change too?

Comment: @user1264377: Not usually unless you have some code that does that.

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much explains it. The Rooms class is associated with type, not with the instance of Session (Room is static). You have to access its functions through Session.Room.Load() etc.